# Regresar dos valores en funcion con return

Tags: php

Estoy mandando esos valores a la funcion getNombre y getprivilegio para despues en otro archivo php extraerlos con `$user->getNombre();` hasta ahi todo bien pero me preguntaba como podria regresar 2 o mas valores en una funcion. He leido mucho sobre guardarlo en un array como este:

```
function números_pequeños()
{
    return array (0, 1, 2);
}
list ($cero, $uno, $dos) = números_pequeños();
```

Pero me muestra un erro en la list y realmente no entiendo que mas hacer con esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola la funcion podria devolver dos valores en un array asociativo, como se muestra.

```
 function getNombre(){
 return array(
'nombre1' => 'Alex',
'nombre2' => 'Juan'
);
    }
```

y luego recibir los datos de esta manera.

```
$nombre1 = ($user->getNombre())['nombre1'];
$nombre2 = ($user->getNombre())['nombre2'];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Clinton, funciona perfectamente.